What happens if you are in wudu but you eat, do you have to wash your mouth to do salah?
What happens if you are in Wudu but you eat, do you have to wash your mouth to do Salah?
and if there are a bunch of food particles in your mouth i think you can swallow it but what you eat but it leaves very little but to no residue do you have to wash your mouth or not?
